# handwritten typeface / name of a typeface in calligraphy

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a handwriting art style called?

So, when a calligraphy artist writes words in a certain way, the letter have certain forms and follow some style.

On a computer different typefaces describe these differences; Papyrus vs Comic Sans vs Arial vs Times New Roman.

What's the equivalent of this word "typeface" but for calligraphic art?

> The ______ is beautiful

---

> The ____________ of the all-caps small writing is different to the __________ of the larger lowercase writing in the below image

[image]

---

> The following images show two different ____________s

[image]

[image]

> You can tell they are different ________s because the tail of the 'g', for example, is drawn so differently in each case

Comment: Aren't you just talking about hands? So like book hands, secretary hands, chancery hands, court hands, etc. Or do you mean scripts like uncial, half-uncial, old Roman cursive, Carolingian miniscule, etc? Or like Copperplate?

Answer (score 2):

***Hand***, ***script***, or ***alphabet***

[This blog post](https://medium.com/@dsingz.seo/western-calligraphy-ba2121720390) is entitled *Western calligraphy* and just literally says *A style of writing is described as a script, hand or alphabet.* The Wikipedia article on [Western calligraphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_calligraphy) gives the following two as references for the same claim, but I don't have access to them: M. Fraser and W. Kwiatowski, *Ink and Gold: Islamic Calligraphy* (2006) and E. Johnston, *Writing, Illuminating & Lettering* (1906, Dover ed. 1995).

On the other hand, [this source](https://books.google.com/books?id=gVh0DwAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PP1&dq=Calligraphy%20hand&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q=hand&f=false) gives examples and uses the names 'alphabets', 'scripts', and 'hands' (*skeleton hand, foundational hand, unical hand, blackletter hand*, …).

Here are the Wikipedia articles on various hands: [secretary hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_hand), [book hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_hand), [Chancery hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chancery_hand), [Carolingian minuscule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carolingian_minuscule) (which is referred to as *script* in the text).